# VBA - Syntax of the SaveAs-Method

Tags: vba, excel

Implementing the FileFilter parameter one has to use comma-separated pairs of a describer followed by a file extension.

```
<pre>fileName = _
Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
InitialFileName:="my_file", _
FileFilter:="Text File (*.txt), *.txt, _
XML File (*.xml), *.xml")</pre>
```

I have played with the method. The file-extension is determined by the extension in parenthesis.

So, what's the purpose of the file-extension AFTER the comma? 
In my code-example *.txt and *.xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The piece of text before the comma is what is shown in the File Filter drop down menu; the extension after the comma is the actual extension used to filter when the appropriate menu option is selected.

In your case, the two menu options will be `Text File (*.txt)` and `XML File (.xml)`. When they are selected, they will use `.txt` and `.xml` respectively to filter the visible options.

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195734.aspx):

> This string passed in the FileFilter argument consists of pairs of file filter strings followed by the MS-DOS wildcard file filter specification, with each part and each pair separated by commas. Each separate pair is listed in the Files of type drop-down list box.